# JupyterLab 3: how to get the list of running servers

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyter-server

Since JupyterLab 3.x jupyter-server is used instead of the classic notebook server, and the following code does not list servers served with `jupyter_server`:

```
from notebook import notebookapp 
notebookapp.list_running_servers()
None
```

---

What still works for the file/notebook name is:

```
from time import sleep
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
import subprocess
import os
import uuid

def get_notebook_path_and_save():
    magic = str(uuid.uuid1()).replace('-', '')
    print(magic)
    # saves it (ctrl+S)
    # display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.save_checkpoint();')) # Javascript Error: IPython is not defined
    nb_name = None
    while nb_name is None:
        try:
            sleep(0.1)
            nb_name = subprocess.check_output(f'grep -l {magic} *.ipynb', shell=True).decode().strip()
        except:
            pass
    return os.path.join(os.getcwd(), nb_name)
```

But it's not pythonic nor fast

---

How to get the current running server instances - and so e.g. the current notebook file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration to `jupyter_server` should be as easy as changing `notebook` to `jupyter_server`, `notebookapp` to `serverapp` and changing the appropriate [configuration files](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators/migrate-from-nbserver.html) - the server-related codebase is largely unchanged. In the case of listing servers simply use:

```
from jupyter_server import serverapp
serverapp.list_running_servers()
```